# How can I run a shell script on k8s by using bazel?

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes, bazel

Usually, I run a python script on k8s. When I do this, I define below three and run with
`bazel run my_py_job_k8s.create`

```
py_binary(
    name = "my_py_job",
    srcs = ["my_py_job.py"],
)

py3_image(
    name = "my_py_job_image",
    srcs = ["my_py_job.py"],
    base = "//donguk:base_image",
    main = "my_py_job.py",
    deps = [":my_py_job"],
)

k8s_object(
    name = "my_py_job_k8s",
    cluster = "my_cluster",
    images = {
        "experimental:my_py_job": ":my_py_job_image",
    },
    namespace = "{BUILD_USER}",
    template = ":my_py_job.yaml",
)
```

but this time I need to run shell script on k8s.

I defined similar way and tried to run `bazel build my_sh_job_k8s`, but even build was failed

```
sh_binary(
    name = "my_sh_job",
    srcs = ["my_sh_job.sh"],
)

py3_image(
    name = "my_sh_job_image",
    srcs = ["my_sh_job.sh"],
    base = "//donguk:base_image_2",
    main = "my_sh_job.py",
    deps = [":my_sh_job"],
)

k8s_object(
    name = "my_sh_job_k8s",
    cluster = "my_cluster",
    images = {
        "experimental:my_sh_job": ":my_sh_job_image",
    },
    namespace = "{BUILD_USER}",
    template = ":my_sh_job.yaml",
)
```

Error message

```
BUILD:12:10: in srcs attribute of py_binary rule //experimental/tools:my_sh_job_image.binary: source file '//experimental/tools:my_sh_job.sh' is misplaced here (expected .py or .py3). Since this rule was created by the macro 'py3_image', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation
```

So it seems that I should've not use `py3_image` for shell script, but I couldn't find which image format to use. There is no `sh_image`, do I need to use `container_image` in this case? or shell scripts files are not allow to run on k8s?

Comment: `py_image` rule accepts only `py` files in `srcs` not `bash`. 

As a workaround what you can do is call your`my_sh_job.sh` from your "my_py_job.py".